# Accessing and modifying code in the APEX 19.1 buttons created through the wizard

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

Beginner here.

How can I access and modify the code of the different buttons that are created when using APEX wizards (like the `CREATE` or `SAVE` button for instance.)

Can you help please with detailed instructions.

Comment: What do you mean by "access and modify the code"? What code?

Comment: What I mean is this. The 'CREATE' or 'SAVE' button of the forms created by the APEX wizards execute a default code when I click them. What if I wanted to write my custom code instead, where would I add my code?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at button's properties. What it does, is described under "Behavior". For example, `CREATE` button will

- submit page
- perform SQL insert action

Furthermore, have a look at processes Apex created for you; you'll find *Automatic Row Processing* which is responsible for insert/update/delete.

If you want to create your own code that stands behind that button, create your own process. Its type might then be "PL/SQL Code" which calls a stored procedure, passes page items' values to it, whatever. Scroll down the process' properties to **Server-side Condition** which lets you specify **button** which should be pressed in order for that process to run - you'd choose the `CREATE` button here.

I guess that's it.